# Compiling CSS on OSX Lion in CodeKit - File to import not found or unreadable: compass

Tags: compass-sass, codekit

Having an issue with CodeKit compiling my SCSS files. It works via Terminal with `compass compile` or `compass watch` but within CodeKit it throws this error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
          Load path: /
```

The line that it's complaining about is:

```
@import "compass";
```

I've installed compass the standard way and put my project into CodeKit but have no idea why it's dying here... I've had a google around but most people are complaining about 'zurb-foundation' and their issue commonly being they didn't import it in their compass.rb file. Here it's JUST compass.

I've tried `sudo gem update` but nothing seems to get CodeKit to compile properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Zend Framework and was adding the root directory to CodeKit. It seems I had to add the `public` folder to get it to work as it then recognised my `project` as a Compass project and worked then with SASS in that root directory.